# Which is the appropriate stack for Creative Commons license questions?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I have some questions about interoperability between Creative Commons licenses that aren't answered on the [CC FAQ](https://wiki.creativecommons.org/Frequently_Asked_Questions). I believe that my question falls on the simple/practical side of the line, rather than something tricky requiring actual legal advice. Is there a stack for this? (So far I've found the [Law proposal](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/67858/law), and I'm not sure if it's a good fit.)

Example question, *Can I copy a CC-BY-SA 3.0 work and distribute it (unmodified) under CC-BY-SA 4.0?*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://opensource.stackexchange.com covers any freely licensed works, not just software, including questions about CC licensing. (Note: It is currently in beta and [may be renamed](https://opensource.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/542/more-site-name-brainstorming-part-iii).)

Answer (score 2):

The [Open Data](https://opendata.stackexchange.com) stack (in beta as of this writing) seems to be the best fit for questions relating to data licenses (rather than software specifically)

> Open Data Stack Exchange is a question and answer site for developers and researchers interested in open data.

Where open data is defined as...

> Open means anyone can freely access, use, modify, and share for any purpose (subject, at most, to requirements that preserve provenance and openness).
>
> *(from http://opendefinition.org)*

And indeed [my question](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/3652) already has an answer, and I have found more besides.

Answer (score 1):

[Programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com) has a number of questions tagged [creative-commons](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/creative-commons) that seem to have a similar scope.

Comment: I believe I have found a more specific stack (open data) to post my question, but I will definitely check out the existing questions at programmers, thanks!

Comment: link for anyone wanting confirmation that (software) licensing questions are valid at Programmers https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/165980